# iterating from a tuple of tuples optimizations

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

Basic problem: take a list of digits, find all permutations, filter, filter again, and sum.
this is my first python script so after some research i decided to use itertools.permutations. i then iterate through the tuple, and create a new tuple of tuples with only the tuples i wanted. i then concatenate the tuples because I want the permutations as numbers, not as broken strings.
then i do one more filter and sum them together.

for 8 digits, this is taking me about 2.5 seconds, far too slow if i want to scale to 15 digits (my goal). 
(I decided to use tuples since a list of the permutations will be too large for memory)

**EDIT:** I realized that I don't care about the sum of the permutations, but rather just the count. If going the generator path, how could I include a counter instead of taking the sum?
Updated my original code with [very] slight improvements shortcuts also, as to not just copy pasta suggested answers before I truly understand them.

```
import itertools

digits= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
digital=(itertools.permutations(digits))


mytuple=()
for i in digital:
    q=''
    j=list(i)
    if j[0] != 0:
        for k in range(len(j)):
            q=q+str(j[k])

        mytuple=mytuple+(q,)

#print mytuple

z = [i for i in mytuple if i%7==0]

print len(z)
```

this being my first python script, any non-optimization pointers would also be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: You can just do if j:  to check if j is non-empty

Comment: Also i.join() will join a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Generator comprehensions" are your friend. Not least because a "generator" only works on one element at a time, helping you save memory.   Also, some time can be saved by pre-computing the relevant powers of 10 and performing integer arithmetic instead of converting to and from strings:

```
import itertools

digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
oom = [ 10 ** i for i, digit in enumerate( digits ) ][ ::-1 ] # orders of magnitude
allperm = itertools.permutations( digits )

firstpass = ( sum( a * b for a, b in zip( perm, oom ) ) for perm in allperm if perm[ 0 ] )

print sum( i for i in firstpass if i % 7 == 0 )
```

This is faster than the original by a large factor, but the factorial nature of permutations means that 15 digits is *still* a long way away. I get 0.05s for `len(digits)==8`,  0.5s for `len(digits)==9`, but 9.3s for `len(digits)==10`...

Since you're working in base 10, `digits` sequences of length >10 will contain repeats, leading to repeats in the set of permutations. Your strategy will need to change if the repeats are not supposed to be counted separately (e.g. if the question is phrased as "how many 15-digit multiples of 7 are repermutations of the following digits...").

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info about generators. I've updated the question to not care about the sum of the permutations, but simply the quantity. How would I build a counter into the generator instead of just taking the sum?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is `sum( i % 7 == 0  for i in firstpass )` which sums up a sequence of `True` and `False` values (recasting them to integers 1 or 0 respectively)

Comment: Saw the edits. I have come to the conclusion that I simply have to approach this differently and not generate all permutations, because for increasing N no amount of optimization will negate the fact that I have 2.4 quintillion permutations (for N=20). Regardless, I really appreciate these insights and have incorporated a lot of these shortcuts into other problems I'm tackling. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is a good choice. Well investigated.

I tried to improve the nice solution of @jez. I rearanged the `range`, replaced `zip` through `izip` and cached the lookup in a local variable.

```
N = 10
gr = xrange(N-1,-1,-1)
ap = itertools.permutations(gr)
o = [10 ** i for i in gr]
zip = itertools.izip
print sum(i for i in (sum(a*b for a, b in zip(p, o)) for p in ap if p[0]) if i % 7 == 0)
```

For me it's about 17% faster for N=9 and 7% for N=10. The speed improvement may is negligible for larger N's, but not tested.

Comment: I saw a similar speed improvement when I tried. On account that this would still take months (if not years for higher N) to calculate, I'm going to try to investigate alternate solutions. This has been a great help regardless though, thanks!

Comment: I've updated the question to not care about the sum of the permutations, but simply the quantity. How would I build a counter into the generator instead of just taking the sum?

Comment: Nice use of `izip`. To count instead of summate, you could change just one character: `sum(1 for ...` instead of `sum(i for...`

Answer (score 0):

There are many short-cuts in python you're missing.  Try this:

```
import itertools

digits= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
digital=(itertools.permutations(digits))

mytuple=set()
for i in digital:
    if i[0] != 0:
        mytuple.add(int(''.join(str(d) for d in i)))

z = [i for i in mytuple if i%7==0]

print sum(z)
```

Might be hard to get to 15 digits though.  **15!** is 1.3 trillion...if you could process 10 million permutations per second, it would still take 36 hours.

Comment: We may should eliminate the string operations somehow just add it to a value.

Comment: Can you help explain a bit what you're doing with the variable 'mytuple'. I wanted to use tuples b/c a list will exceed memory capacity, but I you're doing it as a set. I understand this will make entries unique, but will there be memory issues?

Comment: I doubt there's much difference memory wise between a list, set, or tuple.  The main differences would be around uniqueness, and speed of operations.  Appending to a set or list is O(1).  You can't append to a tuple, so your code is creating a brand new tuple each time.  Very Slow!

Comment: Got it thanks for the extra info! The reason I was using a tuple is for large N, you can't take `list(digital)` because it's too large for memory. I was wondering if the same would happen with sets.